# how to load image from web?

Tags: android

hello all i have image url getting from web and now i want to display that in may imageview.

pls helm me out.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: What have you tried so far? What results did you get? How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (please be more specific, these are not self-evident from the current state of your question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below i mentioned one function that will load image from web and convert it into drawable . So you can set that drawable into ImageView.

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url) 
{
    try 
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```